# <p:ajax> Event:pointSelect is not supported

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

`enter code here`I try to use primefaces' gmap and when I put the EventView codes' into my xhtml I get the error.

What I am trying to do is, I want to get longitude and latitude informations from gmap and fill my textboxes.

I tried to put p:ajax tags into p:inputText as mentioned in "Primefaces Ajax ItemSelect Event Not Supported" topic but it did not work for me

my xhtml page:

```
<h:form>

 <center>
 <br></br>

 <p:column>


<p:inputText value="#{userAddPlaceBean.place.placeName}" id="name">Place Name </p:inputText>

  <p:inputText value="#{userAddPlaceBean.place.lng}" id="lng"> Longitude 
  <p:ajax event="pointSelect" listener="#{eventView.onPointSelect}" update="lng" />
  </p:inputText>

  <p:inputText value="#{userAddPlaceBean.place.lat}" id="lat"> Latitude 
  <p:ajax event="pointSelect" listener="#{eventView.onPointSelect}" update="lat" />
  </p:inputText>


 <br />
 <br />
 <center>
  <p:commandButton action="#{userAddPlaceBean.addPlace()}" value="Add Place"></p:commandButton>
 </center>

</p:column>
</center>
<br></br>
<br></br>
  <center><a href="#{request.contextPath}/user/userplacelist.xhtml">Show Places</a></center> 

</h:form>
```

Comment: Your pointSelect events are inside your p:inputText and that is not correct. InputText does not have a pointSelectevent.  You need to put your pointSelectEvent inside your GMAP component to subscribe to that event.

Comment: @Melloware: sounds like a valid answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your "pointSelect" events are inside your **p:inputText** and that is not correct. InputText does not have a pointSelectevent. You need to put your pointSelectEvent inside your GMAP component to subscribe to that event.

Example:

```xml
<p:gmap>
   <p:ajax event="pointSelect" listener="#{eventView.onPointSelect}" update="lat" />
</p:gmap>
```

Comment: That is true, that works in gmap but that way inputTexts do not work in gmap. Thanks anyway, it seems this leads me another question :)